# Generics: Pass map with derived types

Tags: go, generics

In the following example `foo` and `bar` are basically of the same type: `map[uint32]string`.
Nevertheless go1.18beta complains that: `M2 does not match map[K]V`.

Is it even possible to get `equal` to accept both of these maps? Do I need to change the signature of `equal` or the declarations of the maps itself?

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func equal[M1, M2 ~map[K]V, K, V comparable](m1 M1, m2 M2) bool {
    if len(m1) != len(m2) {
        return false
    }
    for k, v1 := range m1 {
        if v2, ok := m2[k]; !ok || v1 != v2 {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}

type (
    someNumericID uint32
    someStringID  string
)

func main() {
    foo := map[uint32]string{
        10: "bar",
    }

    bar := map[someNumericID]someStringID{
        10: "bar",
    }

    if equal(foo, bar) == true {
        fmt.Println("Maps are the same")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Maps are not the same")
    }
}
```

Comment: Both your `M1` and `M2` map types have identical key and value types (`K` and `V`), yet the ones you want to pass have not.

Comment: @icza Trying to understand better, you mean named types are not considered as equal here?

Comment: Yes, the type `someNumericID` does not equal to `uint32`. A type definition creates a new type. If you have a value of type `uint32`, you can't index `bar` with that value (without explicit type conversion).

Comment: Also note that you can't compare values of _different_ types. So you can't compare a value of `uint32` to a value of `someNumericID`, that's a compile time error. You need explicit type conversion.

Comment: Now you can use: https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/exp/maps#Equal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it even possible to get equal to accept both of these maps?

Yes, but you have to differentiate the key and value types, as they are not the same. This is what the fixed function could look like:

```
func equal[K1, K2 ~uint32, V1, V2 ~string](m1 map[K1]V1, m2 map[K2]V2) bool {
    if len(m1) != len(m2) {
        return false
    }
    for k, v1 := range m1 {
        if v2, ok := m2[K2(k)]; !ok || V2(v1) != v2 {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

In particular, both keys and value type parameters are constrained to the respective approximate elements `~uint32` and `~string` in order to allow the conversions `m2[K2(k)]` and `V2(v1)` in the function body. This is required to compare values (including map indexing) that don't have the same type, but have the same *underlying* type.

The above solution forgoes type parameters `M1` and `M2` on the map types — due to what appears to be a compiler bug; see comments for details —, but since you are not actually using those types in the function body, nor in return values, [they are not strictly needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71063663/whats-the-difference-between-a-generic-slice-argument-and-an-argument-constrain).

Playground: https://gotipplay.golang.org/p/Y8C_8ilsXUg

---

If you want to understand why your first example failed, here's a breakdown. The relevant paragraph in the language specs is [Type inference](https://tip.golang.org/ref/spec#Type_inference).

1. In `equal[M1, M2 ~map[K]V, K, V comparable](m1 M1, m2 M2)`, the type params `M1` and `M2` have the same constraint `~map[K]V`.
2. When you call the function without explicit instantiation, the compiler tries to infer the type parameters from the types of the supplied arguments. In short, it infers `K` and `V` from `M1`, so `equal(foo, bar)` where `foo` is `map[uint32]string` results in `K = uint32` and `V = string`.
3. The instantiated constraint is then `M1, M2 ~map[uint32]string`
4. Now there's no more type params to infer, so it just type-checks `bar` against the instantiated constraint. Is the underlying (`~`) type of `bar` the same as `map[uint32]string`? No. Even if the underlying types of keys and vals are the same, the underlying type of the entire map is exactly `map[someNumericID]someStringID`.
5. Instantiation of `equal` with args `foo` and `bar` fails.

<sup>This becomes more apparent if instead of relying on type inference, you instantiate `equal` with explicit type args. By specifying just `M1` and `M2` (remember that they have the same constraint): `equal[map[uint32]string, map[uint32]string](foo, bar)` then `bar` obviously doesn't match.</sup>