# Why does maps.Keys() in Go specify the map type as M?

Tags: go, generics

I had a function implemented to obtain the keys in a map (a few versions actually, for different types), which I updated to use generics in Go 1.18.  Then I found out that the experimental library was extended to include that functionality, and while my implementation was nearly identical, the function declaration has some differences that I would like to better understand.

Here is my original generic version (I renamed the variables to match the standard library, to better highlight was is actually different):

```golang
func mapKeys[K comparable, V any](m map[K]V) []K {
    r := make([]K, 0, len(m))
    for k := range m {
        r = append(r, k)
    }
    return r
}
```

And here is the [experimental library version](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/exp/maps#Keys):

```golang
func Keys[M ~map[K]V, K comparable, V any](m M) []K {
    r := make([]K, 0, len(m))
    for k := range m {
        r = append(r, k)
    }
    return r
}
```

As you can see, the main difference is the extra `M ~map[K]V` type parameter, which I omitted and directly used `map[K]V` for the function's argument type.  My function works, so why would I need to go through the extra trouble of adding a third parameterized type?

As I was writing my question, I thought I had figured out the answer: to be able to invoke the function on types that are really maps under the covers, but are not directly declared as such, like maybe on this `DataCache` type:

```golang
type DataCache map[string]DataObject
```

My thinking was that this probably required the `~map` notation, and the `~` can only be used in a type constraint, not in an actual type.  Only problem with this theory: my version works fine on such map types.  So I am at a loss as to what it's useful for.

Comment: Note that `Keys` and `Values` were removed from the `maps` package before `maps` became part of the standard library for Go 1.21. Those functions will likely be back in one form or another later. See [this issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/61538) for details and discussion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**tl;dr** it is relevant in the *very uncommon* case where you need to declare a variable of function type (without calling it), and you instantiate that function with a named map type from another package that uses unexported types in its definition.

---

Using a named type parameter in function signatures is mostly relevant when you need to accept **and return** defined types, as you correctly guessed, and as @icza answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71063663/whats-the-difference-between-a-generic-slice-argument-and-an-argument-constrain) with respect to the `x/exp/slices` package.

Your remark that "tilde types" can only be used in interface constraints is also correct.

Now, almost all functions in the `x/exp/maps` package do not actually return the named type `M`. The only one that actually does is [`maps.Clone`](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/exp/maps#Clone) with signature:

```
func Clone[M ~map[K]V, K comparable, V any](m M) M
```

However declaring the signature **without** the approximate constraint `~map[K]V` still works for defined types thanks to [type unification](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Type_unification). From the specs:

> [...], because a defined type `D` and a type literal `L` are never equivalent, **unification compares the underlying type of D with L** instead

And a code example:

```
func Keys[K comparable, V any](m map[K]V) []K {
    r := make([]K, 0, len(m))
    for k := range m {
        r = append(r, k)
    }
    return r
}

type Dictionary map[string]int

func main() {
    m := Dictionary{"foo": 1, "bar": 2}
    k := Keys(m)
    fmt.Println(k) // it just works
}
```

Playground: https://go.dev/play/p/hzb2TflybZ9

The case where the additional named type parameter `M ~map[K]V` is relevant is when you need to pass around **an instantiated value of the function**:

```
func main() {
    // variable of function type!
    fn := Keys[Dictionary]
    
    m := Dictionary{"foo": 1, "bar": 2}
    fmt.Println(fn(m))
}
```

Playground: https://go.dev/play/p/hks_8bnhgsf

Without the `M ~map[K]V` type parameter, it would not be possible to instantiate such a function value with defined types. Of course you could instantiate your function with `K` and `V` separately like

```
fn := Keys[string, int]
```

But this is not viable when the defined map type belongs to a different package and references unexported types:

```
package foo 

type someStruct struct{ val int }

type Dictionary map[string]someStruct
```

and:

```
package main

func main() {
    // does not compile
    // fn := Keys[string, foo.someStruct]

    // this does
    fn := maps.Keys[foo.Dictionary]
}
```

Though, this seems a rather esoteric use case.

You can see the final playground here: https://go.dev/play/p/B-_RBSqVqUD

However keep in mind that `x/exp/maps` is an experimental package, so the signatures may be changed with future Go releases, and/or when these functions get promoted into the standard library.