# Why do functions in the slices package define a type parameter for the slice argument?

Tags: go, generics

Why is the BinarySearch function in the slices package defined like this:

```golang
func BinarySearch[S ~[]E, E cmp.Ordered](x S, target E) (int, bool)
```

And not like this:

```golang
func BinarySearch[E cmp.Ordered](x []E, target E) (int, bool)
```

I tried to write code that works with the first one and does not compile with the second definition. But I'm new to go and I have no idea.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71905177/why-does-maps-keys-in-go-specify-the-map-type-as-m/71905349#71905349

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`BinarySearch` can be written either way; in fact the definition [used to be](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/0df681248862a34ff1233cdc4cf0b036e4761652:src/slices/sort.go;l=120):

`func BinarySearch[E cmp.Ordered](x []E, target E) (int, bool)`

It was changed to:

`func BinarySearchFunc[S ~[]E, E, T any](x S, target T, cmp func(E, T) int) (int, bool)`

following the proposal in [this issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/60546). The [commit](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/502955) explains the reason for the change:

> slices: consistently use S ~[]E
>
> Make all functions use a constraint S ~[]E even if they don't return
> the slice type. This makes explicitly instantiating the functions more
> consistent: you don't have to remember which take ~[]E and which do not.
> It also permits inferring the type when passing one of these functions
> to some other function that is using a named slice type.